# How do I manage multiple submit buttons in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

I am currently working on a Django quiz app and I want to do manage the submit button for each option.

```html
<form method='POST'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col'>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block button" name='option1' onclick=''>{{ option1 }}</button>
    </div>
    <div class='col'>
      <button name='option2' class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block button" onclick=''>{{ option2 }}</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col'>
      <button name='option3' class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block button" onclick=''>{{ option3 }}</button>
    </div>
    <div class='col'>
      <button name='option4' class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block button" onclick=''>{{ option4 }}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If they are submit buttons and you do not use AJAX, then you will get option1=value1 if you add value="value1" to that button etc

Comment: Would you mind explaining it further?

Comment: If you submit a form using one or more submit buttons, if you give the button a name and a value, the server will receive the name=value of the button clicked

Answer (score 0):

In the template form:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit_name" value="Approve"/> 
<input type="submit" name="submit_name" value="Cancel"/>
```

In view:

```
submit = request.POST.get('submit_name')
if "Approve" in submit:
    # Do something
elif: "Cancel" in submit:
    # Do something else
```